# what's the usage of __traceback_hide__

Tags: python

I have seen this line of code in some functions

```
__traceback_hide__ = True
```

What does it do? It seems like its trying to suppress the error traceback. In what situations should the traceback be hidden?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`__tracebackhide__` can be set to hide a function from the traceback when using PyTest. `__traceback_hide__` appears to be used in the Python Paste package for the same purpose.

Here's what the [paste.exceptions.collector](http://pythonpaste.org/modules/exceptions.html#module-paste.exceptions.collector) documentation has to say about it:

> If set and true, this indicates that the frame should be hidden from abbreviated tracebacks. This way you can hide some of the complexity of the larger framework and let the user focus on their own errors.
>
> By setting it to 'before', all frames before this one will be thrown away. By setting it to 'after' then all frames after this will be thrown away until 'reset' is found. In each case the frame where it is set is included, unless you append '_and_this' to the value (e.g., 'before_and_this').
>
> Note that formatters will ignore this entirely if the frame that contains the error wouldn’t normally be shown according to these rules.

And the [PyTest documentation](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#writing-well-integrated-assertion-helpers) on its similar `__tracebackhide__`:

> If you have a test helper function called from a test you can use the pytest.fail marker to fail a test with a certain message. The test support function will not show up in the traceback if you set the __tracebackhide__ option somewhere in the helper function.

So basically, they are to avoid cluttering your tracebacks with test helper functions or other functions that you know aren't part of the problem that you are trying to debug.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like this is [mostly a convenience for web frameworks](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/issues/160) (Sentry, werkzeug, [Paste](http://pythonpaste.org/modules/exceptions.html#paste.exceptions.collector.ExceptionCollector), Django) to make it so framework functions aren't included in the high level exception reporting features of the frameworks.

The exact behavior likely differs by framework, for example, for Paste specifically, it's documented as:

> If set and true, this indicates that the frame should be hidden from abbreviated tracebacks. This way you can hide some of the complexity of the larger framework and let the user focus on their own errors.
>
> By setting it to 'before', all frames before this one will be thrown away. By setting it to 'after' then all frames after this will be thrown away until 'reset' is found. In each case the frame where it is set is included, unless you append '_and_this' to the value (e.g., 'before_and_this').
>
> Note that formatters will ignore this entirely if the frame that contains the error wouldn’t normally be shown according to these rules.

It's not a standard variable, and the core Python interpreter provides no support for it.

Comment: Frameworks in **general** (not _just_ web frameworks).  Such as the [Bluesky framework](https://blueskyproject.io) for data acquisition.  Use of `__tracebackhide__` might help in resolving this [request to reduce the detail in exception reports](https://github.com/bluesky/bluesky/issues/1274).

Answer (score 4):

Hiding the traceback can give you more comprehensible test output.

Consider testing that a web API endpoint `/running` returns the JSON response `{"running": true}`:

```py
import pytest
import json

def test_running(client):
    action_response = client.get('/running')
    assert parse_as_json(action_response) == {'running': True}

def parse_as_json(response):
    __tracebackhide__ = True  # <---- Point of interest
    try:
        return json.loads(response.data)
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        pass
    pytest.fail(f'Expected JSON, but got {response.data}')
```

If the test fails (because the JSON is malformed), then the failure will be displayed as

```
__________________________ test_running _________________________

client = <FlaskClient <Flask 'webapi'>>

    def test_running(client):
        action_res = client.get('/running')
>       assert parse_as_json(action_res) == {'running': True}
E       Failed: Expected JSON, but got b'ok'

webapi_test.py:22: Failed
=============== 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.15 seconds ===============
```

whereas, without the `__tracebackhide__ = True`, the output will be

```
__________________________ test_running _________________________

client = <FlaskClient <Flask 'webapi'>>

    def test_running(client):
        action_res = client.get('/running')
>       assert parse_as_json(action_res) == {'running': True}

webapi_test.py:22: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

client = <FlaskClient <Flask 'webapi'>>

    def test_running(client):
        action_res = client.get('/running')
>       assert parse_as_json(action_res) == {'running': True}
E       Failed: Expected JSON, but got b'ok'

webapi_test.py:22: Failed
=============== 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.17 seconds ===============
```

Answer (score 2):

Googling for "python __traceback_hide__", I learn that it's intended to let a complicated framework hide part of its inner workings by suppressing some stack frames from the exception printout, so that the user does not become confused lots of irrelevant output.